# C# Multiply 2 Data Grid View columns from input and place result in third column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on a POS winforms application, and I'm having trouble, the datagridview is filled by user input, through a barcode scanner, and then the user adjusts the Quantity inside the data grid view, what I want to do is when the user changes the value of Quantity ( which is set to 1 by default) it gets multiplied by second column which is price and show the result in the third column

Column A (value entered) x Column B = Result to Column C

I've tried using this code, but no luck

```
            private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
            int a =dataGridView1.Rows[i][0].value;
            int b =dataGridView1.Rows[i][1].value;

            int c = a*b;

            c=dataGridView1.Rows[i][2].value;


      }
```

it gave me Error 14 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Cells` property of the `DataGridViewRow` class

Use:

```
int a = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
int b = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;

int c = a * b;

dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = c;
```

Please note, I change the last line to be `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = c;` as that seems to match your question...you want the answer stored in the cell.

Comment: Thanks Jay, but that is giving me Error 13 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JoeyArnanzo, sorry, I used the wrong case for `Value`. Answer changed to correct casing for `Value`

Comment: Oh got it thanks, I think it should be converted to int32

Comment: int and Int32 are the same thing. That part won't make a difference. But, you may want to consider changing the type of a, b, and c to be a decimal to take in to account pennies or part quantities (if that is possible for you)

Comment: You are right about that, but I still seem unable to get it to work, no errors, but nothing is showing. should it be placed in another void?

Comment: ok I edited this line and now works fine dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = c.ToString(); ... but it is only calculating when I click on any cell, is there a way to make it calculate without clicking anything as well as clicking?

Answer (score 0):

```
            decimal s = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView_DaginaAdd_SellInovice.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value);
            decimal s1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView_DaginaAdd_SellInovice.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value);
            decimal s13 = s + s1; Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView_DaginaAdd_SellInovice.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value = s13);
```